# Check for existing row before doing insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, select, insert

Table1 columns:

> clinic_code, schedule_date, schedule_time, source_id

Table2 columns:

> clinic_code, schedule_date, schedule_time

There is a stored procedure that does:
1. Delete all records in Table1 where clinic_code='ABC' AND schedule_date=xyz 
2. INSERT all records from table2 where table2.clinic_code='ABC' AND table2.schedule_date=xyz into table1.

I want to make a change in step 2.
*2. INSERT all records from table2 where table2.clinic_code='ABC' AND table2.schedule_date=xyz, but don't overwrite those rows in table1 where source_id=2.

Here's the original insert statement in step 2:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT table2.col1, table3.col2, table2.col3
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.col3 = table3.col5 AND etc...
```

Table names, and additional columns have been left out, if it would be helpful, I can put the exact number of columns.

Comment: But you are not using table1 to insert rows, just table2 and table3. Don't you mean you don't want to insert rows where table2.col3 = 2?

Comment: No. Table1 and table2 are very similar (but not exactly) and I don't duplicates, so if there is a row in Table1.col3=2, i don't want that row to be inserted, the rest yes.  Hope that helps, thanks!

Comment: I must say this does not make any sense. Is your example correct? If you have a row in table1 where col3 equals the value 2, no inserts will be done at all, because it will always have a row where table1 col3 is 2. Is there any criterias about t1.col1 = t2.col1 and/or t1.col2 = t3.col2 (as in what is your business key here)?

Comment: Thanks cairnz, I will update the question with additional details about the tables that i think will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow completely, because if you're inserting the rows into table1, table1.col3 won't have a value for those rows yet.  If you just want to avoid having table1.col3 = 2, you could use a where clause like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT table2.col1, table3.col2, table2.col3
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.col3 = table3.col5 AND etc...
WHERE table2.col3 <> 2
```

Which would avoid inserting the value 2 into table1.col3, since table2.col3 is where you're pulling that from.  If I'm missing the point here let me know, but that should do it.

EDIT - given that you've said the records between table1 and table2 are similar, and assuming there's a column you could join on between the two tables, you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT table2.col1, table3.col2, table2.col3
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.col3 = table3.col5 AND etc...
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1 ON tl.colX = table2.colX
WHERE table1.col3 <> 2
```

The idea being that you've now included table1 in your SELECT and as such can also include it in your WHERE clause.  (Forgive me if the aliasing syntax is off for other SQL flavors, I'm mostly experienced in T-SQL.)

Comment: Not exactly, since table1 will already have records in it.  REcords similar to table2.  So i want to the records inserted, just not those that have table1.col3 = 2.  On those records the row should stay the same in table1.

Comment: This is kinda hard with the generic column names and your join ending with AND etc...my thinking is some kind of join between table1 and table2 that you can then use to exclude the rows you don't want based on table1.col3 having a value of 2.  What exactly is similar between table1 and table2?  Do they have any foreign key relationships between them?

Comment: Thanks Zannjaminderson, I think you are on to something. The PK on the table is made up of col1 and col2.  I have the issue that if make col3 part of the primary key then it gets inserted and I have 2 of the same row, one with col3=2 and one with col3=1.  If i keep the PK as is, I get an error conflict that another row with the same PK is attempting to be inserted. How can i get through this?  It's killing me softly. :)

Comment: That where clause was very helpful.  With that, i was able to bring the table1 into the select and use it in the where clause.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know which SQL you are using so here is a standard SQL script:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ;
       IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM dbo.table1 WHERE   col3 = 2 )
       BEGIN ;
           ...your insert goes here
       END ;
COMMIT ;
```

Comment: using MS SQL 2005.  I tried the above, but then none of the other records from table2 get inserted.  (table1 and table2 are very similar.)  Thanks!